# Where can I download Linux-signed-image kernels?

Tags: kernel

I like to test [new kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy~/) but as I'm using a notebook with UEFI I just only limited to regular updates. Is there any repository where I can download the package linux-image-signed-3.XX-X-generic?
Today on machines without the UEFI I download the packages:

```
linux-headers-3.12.0-031200-generic_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.12.0-031200_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_all.deb
linux-image-3.12.0-031200-generic_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_amd64.deb
```

All in repository http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! If you've already downloaded them why not simply copy them to removable media and carry them to the machine you wish to test them on?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to download or add a repository. You can install following [`linux-signed-image-3.x.x.x generic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&searchon=names&keywords=linux-signed-image) packages in 13.10 :

```
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-12-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-13-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-14-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-15-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-17-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-18-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-20-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-22-generic 
linux-signed-image-3.11.0-23-generic
```

Can install them as:

```
sudo apt-get install [PACKAGE NAME]
```